# cronjob with rails - whenever gem is doing nothing, why? (development mode)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, cron

I am trying to auto backup my database every night. I want to use the whenever gem and my application runs still in *development environment*.

i used `wheneverize .` command in my app folder to create the `config/schedule.rb` file, swhcih looks like this:

```
set :output, "/User/eveadmin/rails/feebacker/log/cron_log.log"
set :environment, "development"


every 1.day, :at => '2:30 am'  do
  dump_path = "/User/eveadmin/rails/db_backups/dump#{Date.today.to_s}"
  command "sudo mysqldump -u user -p secretpasswort feedbacker_development > #{dump_path}.sql"
  command "tar -zcvf #{dump_path}.tar.gz #{dump_path}.sql"
  command "rm #{dump_path}.sql"
  runner "Storage.store_dump '#{dump_path}.tar.gz'"
end
```

After deploying it to my server, also currently running in development mode, I used the command

```
whenever --update-crontab feedbacker --set environment=development
```

After this my crontab looks like the following:

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: feedbacker
30 2 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'sudo mysqldump -uroot -prootz feedbacker_development > /User/eveadmin/rails/db_backups/dump2011-07-07.sql >> /User/eveadmin/rails/feebacker/log/cron_log.log 2>&1'

30 2 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'tar -zcvf /User/eveadmin/rails/db_backups/dump2011-07-07.tar.gz /User/eveadmin/rails/db_backups/dump2011-07-07.sql >> /User/eveadmin/rails/feebacker/log/cron_log.log 2>&1'

30 2 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'rm /User/eveadmin/rails/db_backups/dump2011-07-07.sql >> /User/eveadmin/rails/feebacker/log/cron_log.log 2>&1'

30 2 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/thomasmaximini/Sites/rails_projekte/feedbacker && script/rails runner -e development '\''Storage.store_dump '\''\'\'''\''/User/eveadmin/rails/db_backups/dump2011-07-07.tar.gz'\''\'\'''\'''\'' >> /User/eveadmin/rails/feebacker/log/cron_log.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: feedbacker
```

It simply does nothing, no cron.log is generated, no backups are done, nothing. So I dont know what I am doing wrong as there are no errors raised to debug. I hope anybody can help, thanks.

Comment: have you try this command manualy ? They are no espace between -u and root ?

Comment: thanks for looking, yes in my code it is without blanks between -uroot and-ppassword, just did it here when changing the values.. but u're right. that is unfortunately not the problem ;)

Comment: so when running the commands manually they work fine? have you received any mail alerts regarding those cron tasks?